# file does not show up on github after pushing to master

Tags: git, github, push

I'm trying to update files on github from the cli, but getting nowhere.

my steps:

```
$ git add myfile.txt
$ git commit -m 'update message'
done. all 2 files are hidden.
[48a989d 8762548] update message
 3 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 dir1/secrets.yaml.secret
 create mode 100644 dir2/passwds.secret

$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

but when I open the repo on github, myfile.txt does not show up.
ps, as you can see, I am using git-secret. should not affect this problem, but i am mentioning it jic.

Comment: Are you by any chance working on detached HEAD (or not or master, for that matter)?

Comment: pretty sure I did not do a checkout. however, have been working on this repo from two different systems, so that may have contributed.

Comment: If you commit something and then you push a branch and you get a 'everything is up to date' makes me think you are not working on master (which is the branch you pushed). Check with `git status` or `git branch`

Comment: that was the case. I managed to fix it based on your comment. thank you.. was this the correct way to do it btw? I think there may have been a more elegant way... that may be an apropriate answer for SO. could not find anything based on the messages I got. I could edit my question to fit.

Comment: Please post answers as answers. Don't edit them into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the key to knowing what was happening:

> ```
> [48a989d 8762548] scenes
> ```

For each commit, Git prints a few messages:

```
$ git commit -m bar
[master 04ce966] bar
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

The first line has, in square brackets, your current branch name—in this case, mine was `master`—and the new commit's hash ID, abbreviated to something reasonably short, in this case `04ce966`.

The second line has a summary of what changed in existing, new, and deleted files, and any additional lines give you more information about what else might have changed, specifically new and/or removed files.

Your Git printed:

```
48a989d
```

as the first word in the square brackets.  That means you were on a branch *named* `48a989d`.  This is not a very *good* branch name—it looks a lot like a commit hash—but it is a *valid* branch name, just as `cafedad` or `feedbed` or `cabbabe` are all both valid branch names and potentially valid abbreviated commit hashes as well.  So you committed these files, creating a new commit in branch `48a989d`, then pushed using the name `master`, which had not changed.

Checking out `master`, putting the files in there, committing, and pushing succeeded.  You can now run `git branch` to see this odd `48a989d` branch, or just `git branch -D 48a989d` to forcibly delete it if you are sure that there is nothing of value in it.

Edit: I'd recommend using `git branch` to see it, then running `git branch -m 48a989d some-better-name` to change its name to something more obvious and to work with it, if you want to work with it.

Comment: could you write up the commands to merge branch 48a989d with branch master? I think this is the answer I need. Do you know what could have caused me to work on a separate branch?

Comment: `git checkout master; git merge 48a989d` would merge those commits. `48a989d` is the name of the branch, after all. You could rename it: `git branch -m 48a989d bettername`. The way you created the branch is not certain but I'd bet on `git checkout -b 48a989d` when you meant to write `git checkout 48a989d` (to get a detached HEAD on a commit whose hash is 48a989d).

Answer (score 2):

Just change the branch you are viewing on Github from main to master and you will see your files.

[Changing branches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6Nr6.png)

Answer (score 0):

based on eftshift0 comments below, I tried

```
$ git checkout master

error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
    myfile.txt
    dir1/secrets.yaml.secret
    dir2/passwds.secret
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

I think this may help. will back up my repo locally and try to stash the changes

... 5 mins later...

```
$ git stash
$ git checkout master
$ cp ~/backup/myfile.txt .

$ git add .
$ git commit -m 'update message'
$ git push origin master

Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 987 bytes | 987.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (5/5), completed with 5 local objects.
To github.com:marcwagner/install_scripts.git
2a75b58..92bf3de  master -> master
```

thank you!